# Which were the graphic updates of DAoC?

Tags: dark-age-of-camelot

The graphics of [Dark Age of Camelot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Age_of_Camelot) were updated several times.

*What* was changed *when* since the release of DAoC?

I’m refering to *any* visual change, whether the graphic engine was updated or whether only models/textures changed. (However, graphic fixes/updates of single weapons etc. are irrelevant.)

I tried to find a page with **before/after screenshots**, e.g. of a character standing in a city, but with no success.

For example: What was changed in Shrouded Isles? IIRC the water was updated. What else? Were the environment/city/character/mob models updated, too? [In DAoCWiki it only says](http://camelotherald.wikia.com/wiki/Shrouded_Isles):

> displayed in an all-new state-of-the-art graphics engine that make it look as advanced as any game on the market

Comment: I remember the SI water update, it went from a non see through matt color to a shiny reflection, then afterwards they changed it again to a see through shiny reflection. But for the changes i'm afraid you are not going to find them because most sites that reported about the changes have been archived. And sadly you can't find to much about them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

### Shrouded Isles

- water
- shadows

Source: [mmorpg.com: Dark Age of Camelot Shrouded Isles Review](http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm/game/11/view/reviews/load/22/Dark-Age-of-Camelot-Shrouded-Isles-Review.html):

> When I first fired up Shrouded Isles, the most immediately obvious change to the original Dark Age of Camelot was in the graphics department. Many of the textures had been updated, and of particular note were the updated shadow and water graphics. The shadows were much more realistic than the original "blob" shadow, and water rippled and reflected.

Source: [camelotherald.wikia.com: How does each category in the options menu affect gameplay?](http://camelotherald.wikia.com/wiki/How_does_each_category_in_the_options_menu_affect_gameplay%3F):

> Shrouded Isles Water: Shrouded Isles based water.

### Trials of Atlantis

- trees
- terrain/grounds
- water

Source: [ofcamelot.net: FAQ - Trials of Atlantis Info](http://www.ofcamelot.net/faq/viewcategory.asp?cat=22):

> The main two features of the new engine are the new tree textures and the new ground textures. Both of these effects are present in the old world, but are even more spectacular in the new regions.

Source: [en.wikipedia.org: Dark Age of Camelot - Expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Age_of_Camelot#Expansions):

> also includes new terrain graphics for all areas of the game (including trees)

Source: [camelotherald.wikia.com: How does each category in the options menu affect gameplay?](http://camelotherald.wikia.com/wiki/How_does_each_category_in_the_options_menu_affect_gameplay%3F):

> Use Atlantis Trees: If checked, trees in Shrouded Isles and Classic zones will be replaced with the new Trials of Atlantis-style trees.
>   Use Atlantis Terrain: If checked, the terrain will be drawn using new higher resolution textures.
>   […]
>   Reflective Water: Trials of Atlantis based water.

### New Frontiers (Patch 1.70)

- whole new frontier zone incl. new keeps (technically it didn’t update the old frontier zone, but the access to the old FZ was no longer possible)

Source: [camelotherald.wikia.com: New Frontiers](http://camelotherald.wikia.com/wiki/New_Frontiers)

### Catacombs

- player models incl. faces

  - (also mobs?)
- textures in dungeons (except for Darkness Falls)

Source: [en.wikipedia.org: Dark Age of Camelot - Expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Age_of_Camelot#Expansions):

> Also includes new player model graphics and new graphics for all the games' dungeons (except Darkness Falls).

### New Towns (Patch 1.75)

- cities
- outer walls of capital cities

Source: [daocpedia.eu: New Towns](http://daocpedia.eu/dindex.php/New_Towns)

### Darkness Rising

- textures of world models
- textures in capital cities
- textures in Darkness Falls

Source: [en.wikipedia.org: Dark Age of Camelot - Expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Age_of_Camelot#Expansions):

> new graphics for the game world's models (such as barns, haystacks and forts, this includes the Darkness Falls dungeon and the capital cities) which are following the design ideas presented in Mythic's new graphics for the starting cities

### New New Frontiers (Patch 1.90)

- keeps and towers

Source: [en.wikipedia.org: Dark Age of Camelot - Expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Age_of_Camelot#Expansions):

> significant changes to the layout of keeps and towers